# Как оптимизировать sql-запрос?

Tags: sql, оптимизация

Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать запрос. MS SQL SERVER 2014

```
SELECT t3._Fld19180 AS "Время",
       t3._Fld19184 AS "Пользователь",
       t3._Description AS "Процесс/Операция",
       t3.TimeStart
FROM
(
    SELECT t1._Fld19180,
           t1._Fld19184,
           t1._Description,
           t1.TimeStart,
           t1.TimeEnd
    FROM
    (
        SELECT _Fld19180,
               _Fld19184,
               _Description,
               CONVERT( DATE, _Fld19178, 112) AS TimeStart,
               CONVERT( DATE, _Fld19183_T, 112) AS TimeEnd
        FROM rtl_uriy.dbo._InfoRg19176
             INNER JOIN rtl_uriy.dbo._Reference144 ON rtl_uriy.dbo._InfoRg19176._Fld19177RRef = rtl_uriy.dbo._Reference144._IDRRef
    ) AS t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2._Fld19192,
           t2._Fld19196,
           t2._Description,
           t2.TimeStart,
           t2.TimeEnd
    FROM
    (
        SELECT _Fld19192,
               _Fld19196,
               _Description,
               CONVERT( DATE, _Fld19190, 112) AS TimeStart,
               CONVERT( DATE, _Fld19195_T, 112) AS TimeEnd
        FROM rtl_uriy.dbo._InfoRg19188
             INNER JOIN rtl_uriy.dbo._Reference144 ON rtl_uriy.dbo._InfoRg19188._Fld19189RRef = rtl_uriy.dbo._Reference144._IDRRef
    ) AS t2
) AS t3
WHERE t3._Fld19184 = @username
      AND t3._Description = @form
      AND t3.TimeStart = @date;
```

Запрос должен выгрузить данные на основе нескольких объединенных выборок, это: Среднее время (t3._Fld19180), Имя пользователя (t3._Fld19184), Процесс/Операция (t3._Fld19184), и Дата (t3.TimeStart). Возможно ли как-нибудь его сократить хотя бы?

Заранее все большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Любая оптимизация запроса начинается с просмотра плана выполнения. так же нужно знать полную структуру таблиц со всем индексами и представлять хотя бы примерно природу и особенности данных

Comment: Чтобы помощь получить надо постараться хотя бы пояснить, какая именно помощь нужна, описать проблему и тп. А в таком виде вопрос закроют

Comment: какая субд хотя бы?

Comment: Начинать оптимизацию этого запроса без изменения структуры БД я вообще смысла не вижу, таблицы вроде _InfoRg19188 и _InfoRg19176 не имеют права на существование в нормальной реляционной БД. SQL просто не предназначен для быстрой работы с множеством однотипных таблиц, скорее всего они должны быть объединены в одну

Comment: @Mike - похоже что это какой-то конструктор, наподобие 1С. Очень похожие имена объектов БД

Comment: Использую MS Sql Server 2014. Да, вы правы, это базы 1С. Скажите хотя бы как использовать индексы? Мне бы разобраться как вообще можно оптимизировать...Говорят, что такой запрос ужасен, и лучше его оптимизировать - предлагали разные варианты, временные таблицы, установить минимальный приоритет запроса, добавить индексы..

Comment: Вместо кода гораздо полезнее было бы пояснить, что этот запрос вообще делает и почему решили оптимизировать нативно, а не средствами платформы. И вообще - скорректируйте вопрос, добавьте всю имеющуюся информацию. Иначе помочь просто невозможно

Comment: Нельзя ничего сказать про индексы не увидев данные, потому что индексы доолжны быть подобраны так, что бы у них была высокая селективность, т.е. по одному ключу индекса с условиями из where должно отбираться как можно меньше записей. И повторяю - начинать оптимизацию не видя плана выполнения бесполезно (см. explain)